# How to retrieve array data from children node in Firebase Realtime Database Java? (Firebase Recycler Adapter)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I knew my question is similar with the other questioners but it was not solved my problem because I am still curious about how to declare the item which is the children of parent node. This is my stucture data on my Firebase:

[image]

I've tried to created the classes for my case:

DolanIemClass.java

```
    private String name_tourism;
    private String location_tourism;
    private String info_tourism;
    private String telepon;
    private String url_photo;
    private String url_photo_collage;
    private double lat_location_tourism;
    private double lng_location_tourism;

    public DolanItemClass() {
        //constructor untuk panggilan ke DataSnapshot.getValue
    }

    public DolanItemClass(String name_tourism, String location_tourism, String info_tourism, String telepon, String url_photo, String url_photo_collage, double lat_location_tourism, double lng_location_tourism) {
        this.name_tourism = name_tourism;
        this.location_tourism = location_tourism;
        this.info_tourism = info_tourism;
        this.telepon = telepon;
        this.url_photo = url_photo;
        this.url_photo_collage = url_photo_collage;
        this.lat_location_tourism = lat_location_tourism;
        this.lng_location_tourism = lng_location_tourism;
    }

    public String getUrl_photo_collage() {
        return url_photo_collage;
    }

    public String getName_tourism() {
        return name_tourism;
    }

    public void setName_tourism(String name_tourism) {
        this.name_tourism = name_tourism;
    }

    public String getLocation_tourism() {
        return location_tourism;
    }

    public void setLocation_tourism(String location_tourism) {
        this.location_tourism = location_tourism;
    }

    public String getInfo_tourism() {
        return info_tourism;
    }

    public void setInfo_tourism(String info_tourism) {
        this.info_tourism = info_tourism;
    }

    public String getTelepon() {
        return telepon;
    }

    public void setTelepon(String telepon) {
        this.telepon = telepon;
    }

    public String getUrl_photo() {
        return url_photo;
    }

    public void setUrl_photo(String url_photo) {
        this.url_photo = url_photo;
    }

    public double getLat_location_tourism() {
        return lat_location_tourism;
    }

    public void setLat_location_tourism(double lat_location_tourism) {
        this.lat_location_tourism = lat_location_tourism;
    }

    public double getLng_location_tourism() {
        return lng_location_tourism;
    }

    public void setLng_location_tourism(double lng_location_tourism) {
        this.lng_location_tourism = lng_location_tourism;
    }
}
```

DolanViewHolder.class

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class DolanImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ImageView imgDetailData;

    public DolanImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgDetailData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_detail_item_data);
    }
    public void showImageArray(DolanItemClass dolanItemClass){
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(dolanItemClass.getUrl_photo_collage()).into(imgDetailData);
    }
}
```

And the activity class to show the list

```
package co.id.roningrum.firebasearrayimage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class DetailTouristListAct extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imgDetailData;
    private TextView tvNamaDetail, tvAlamatDetail, tvDescDetail;
    private RecyclerView rvImageDetailCollages;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DolanItemClass, DolanImageViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    public static final String EXTRA_WISATA_KEY = "tourist_key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_tourist_list);

        String touristKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_WISATA_KEY);
        if(touristKey == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass Extra");
        }

        imgDetailData = findViewById(R.id.img_detail_data);
        tvNamaDetail = findViewById(R.id.tv_name_detail);
        tvAlamatDetail = findViewById(R.id.tv_info_tourism_detail);
        tvDescDetail = findViewById(R.id.tv_address_detail);
        rvImageDetailCollages = findViewById(R.id.rv_photo_collage);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tourism").child(touristKey);

        rvImageDetailCollages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        LoadDetailData();

    }

    private void ShowCollage() {
        Query query = databaseReference.child("url_photo_collage");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DolanItemClass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DolanItemClass>()
                .setQuery(query, DolanItemClass.class)
                .build();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DolanItemClass, DolanImageViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DolanImageViewHolder dolanImageViewHolder, int i, @NonNull DolanItemClass dolanItemClass) {
                dolanImageViewHolder.showImageArray(dolanItemClass);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public DolanImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new DolanImageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_image_data, parent, false));
            }
        };
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        rvImageDetailCollages.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    private void LoadDetailData() {
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DolanItemClass dolanItemClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(DolanItemClass.class);
                tvNamaDetail.setText(dolanItemClass.getName_tourism());
                tvAlamatDetail.setText(dolanItemClass.getLocation_tourism());
                tvDescDetail.setText(dolanItemClass.getInfo_tourism());
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(dolanItemClass.getUrl_photo()).into(imgDetailData);
                ShowCollage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
        valueEventListener = eventListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LoadDetailData();
        if(firebaseRecyclerAdapter!=null){
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);

    }
}
```

I expected that I can show the array of `url_photo_collage` node but I don't have any idea for my item class.

Comment: Firebase is all about key-value pair, using array is not a solution.instead you need to define key for each image which stored in firebase storage.

Comment: Do you have suggestion for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your `url_photo_collage` field is declared in your `DolanItemClass` class of type `String` while in your database is an `array`. To solve this, change the type of your field from `String` to a `List<String>` and get it accordingly in your adapter.

Comment: How to call ` List <String> ` in my view holder class?

Comment: Once you change the type of your field, you'll also need to change the corresponding getter and setter. So in the same manner you get the other properties, you can also get this one. `getUrl_photo_collage()` will return a `List<String>` and not a String. Having the list, you can loop through the values to get those urls.

Comment: Okay, you mean like this https://pastebin.com/QjF4Y3E4. I've changed the type of `url_photo_collage` become String

Comment: and the next step, for viewHolder class, what should I change?. Anyway, Thanks for your help

Comment: Now, get that `url_photo_collage` property as a `List<String>` and do what you need to do with it.

Comment: I have done as your suggestion but the recyclerview showed empty.

Comment: Use the debugger to see where it fails. Use breakpoints to see it more clearly.

Comment: In that case, please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.